# Terraform fails with "Can't access attributes on a list of objects." - Cannot access fields on resources created using `for_each = toset(...)`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, continuous-integration, cd

> Terraform fails with "Can't access attributes on a list of objects." - Cannot access fields on resources created using `for_each = toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)`?

`local.domains[*].domain_name` is a list of domains, like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), that I need to convert to a set for use with `for_each`.

How can I iterate over the `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resources individually to create `aws_route53_record` resources?

My current attempt results in the following error, which I don't understand (?):

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../modules/http-api-custom-domain-name/main.tf line 64, in resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway":
│   64:     name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value].domain_name_configuration.target_domain_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway is object with 1 attribute "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│     │ each.value is "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "target_domain_name" for a specific element of the list, or
│ across all elements of the list?
```

Instead of indexing `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resources, I would rather iterate over them directly. Is this possible?

How can I fix the code, so that `aws_route53_record` and `aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping` resources are created for each `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name`?

**Code**:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "api_gateway" {
  for_each = toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)

  domain_name = each.value

  domain_name_configuration {
    certificate_arn = var.certificate_arn == null ? aws_acm_certificate.cert[0].arn : var.certificate_arn
    endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
    security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway" {
  for_each = toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)

  name    = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value].domain_name_configuration.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = local.domain_to_hosted_zone[each.value]

  alias {
    name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value].domain_name_configuration.target_domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value].domain_name_configuration.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "api_gateway" {
  for_each = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[*].domain_name

  api_id      = var.api_gateway_id
  stage_name  = var.api_gateway_stage
  domain_name = each.value
}
```

**Errors**:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../modules/http-api-custom-domain-name/main.tf line 59, in resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway":
│   59:   name    = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value].domain_name_configuration.domain_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway is object with 1 attribute "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│     │ each.value is "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../modules/http-api-custom-domain-name/main.tf line 64, in resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway":
│   64:     name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value].domain_name_configuration.target_domain_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway is object with 1 attribute "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│     │ each.value is "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "target_domain_name" for a specific element of the list, or
│ across all elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../modules/http-api-custom-domain-name/main.tf line 65, in resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway":
│   65:     zone_id                = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value].domain_name_configuration.hosted_zone_id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway is object with 1 attribute "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│     │ each.value is "bff-dev-partner.service-dev.dpt.lego.com"
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "hosted_zone_id" for a specific element of the list, or
│ across all elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../modules/http-api-custom-domain-name/main.tf line 71, in resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "api_gateway":
│   71:   for_each = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[*].domain_name
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "domain_name".
```

Comment: Can you show where you define `local.domains`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) to create multiple resources, Terraform treats these as a *map* of objects, not a list.

In your `aws_route53_record` and `aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping` resources, you are trying to access attributes using a list syntax, but you should be using the map key (which is `each.value` in your case).

That means the syntax to access an attribute of an individual resource needs to be adjusted:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "api_gateway" {
  for_each = toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)

  domain_name = each.value

  domain_name_configuration {
    certificate_arn = var.certificate_arn == null ? aws_acm_certificate.cert[0].arn : var.certificate_arn
    endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
    security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway" {
  for_each = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway

  name    = each.value.domain_name_configuration.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = local.domain_to_hosted_zone[each.key]

  alias {
    name                   = each.value.domain_name_configuration.target_domain_name
    zone_id                = each.value.domain_name_configuration.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "api_gateway" {
  for_each = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway

  api_id      = var.api_gateway_id
  stage_name  = var.api_gateway_stage
  domain_name = each.key
}
```

With this modification, you should no longer encounter the "`Unsupported attribute`" error. Each `aws_route53_record` and `aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping` resource should be correctly associated with each `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resource.

---

However, as noted by [jordanm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77553022/terraform-fails-with-cant-access-attributes-on-a-list-of-objects-cannot-ac#comment136721175_77553022), it depends on how `local.domains` is defined:

- If `local.domains` is a simple list of domain name strings, like `["www.example.com", "api.example.com"]`, the solution above would work as is. That is because `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)` would correctly convert this list into a set of strings, which `for_each` can iterate over.
- If `local.domains` is a list of maps or objects, such as `[{"domain_name": "www.example.com"}, {"domain_name": "api.example.com"}]`, then the way you extract domain names for `for_each` would need to change. Instead of `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)`, you would need to use a more complex expression to extract the domain names from each map/object in the list.
- If `local.domains` has a more complex or nested structure, the solution would need to be tailored to correctly navigate and extract the required information. For example, if `local.domains` includes additional nested attributes or varying levels of details, the method of extracting domain names for `for_each` would need to accommodate this complexity.

---

To detail the second case, when `local.domains` is a list of maps or objects, where each element contains a `domain_name` key, your Terraform configuration would need to extract these domain names differently for use with `for_each`.

Assuming `local.domains` is defined like this:

```
locals {
  domains = [
    { domain_name = "www.example.com" },
    { domain_name = "api.example.com" }
    // other domains
  ]
}
```

Your resources would be defined as follows:

1. **aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name**: Use a `for_each` to iterate over a set of domain names extracted from `local.domains`.

   ```
   resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "api_gateway" {
   for_each = { for d in local.domains : d.domain_name => d.domain_name }

   domain_name = each.value

   domain_name_configuration {
       certificate_arn = var.certificate_arn == null ? aws_acm_certificate.cert[0].arn : var.certificate_arn
       endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
       security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
   }
   }
   ```
2. **aws_route53_record**: Referencing `each.key` and `each.value` based on the `for_each` used in the `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resource.

   ```
   resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway" {
   for_each = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway

   name    = each.value.domain_name_configuration.domain_name
   type    = "A"
   zone_id = local.domain_to_hosted_zone[each.key]

   alias {
       name                   = each.value.domain_name_configuration.target_domain_name
       zone_id                = each.value.domain_name_configuration.hosted_zone_id
       evaluate_target_health = false
   }
   }
   ```
3. **aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping**: Using `each.key` which represents the domain name in this setup.

   ```
   resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "api_gateway" {
   for_each = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway

   api_id      = var.api_gateway_id
   stage_name  = var.api_gateway_stage
   domain_name = each.key
   }
   ```

The `for_each` in `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` is changed to create a map where keys and values are both domain names, extracted from the `local.domains` list of maps. That structure can then be used consistently in the other resources.

---

> Yes, `local.domains` is defined as a list of object.
>
> Why doesn't `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)` work?
> I expect this expression to return a set of domain names.
> `local.domain[*].domain_name` iterates over each domain and extract the domain name?

The confusion arises from the syntax and behavior of Terraform's expressions, specifically when dealing with lists of objects and the splat expression `[*]`.

If `local.domains` is a list of objects, like so:

```
locals {
  domains = [
    { domain_name = "www.example.com" },
    { domain_name = "api.example.com" }
    // other domains
  ]
}
```

The expression `local.domains[*].domain_name` attempts to use the splat expression to extract the `domain_name` attribute from each object in the list. However, this expression does not directly yield a simple list of strings; instead, it results in a complex list of lists due to how Terraform interprets the splat operator with objects.

The correct way to extract a list of strings (domain names in this case) from a list of objects in Terraform is to use a [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for):

```
[for domain in local.domains : domain.domain_name]
```

That `for` expression iterates over each object in `local.domains` and extracts the `domain_name` attribute, resulting in a flat list of strings.

Once you have a flat list of domain names, you can convert it to a set for use with `for_each`:

```
toset([for domain in local.domains : domain.domain_name])
```

That expression creates a set of domain names from `local.domains`, which can be used with `for_each` in your resource definitions.

So, when you tried to use `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)`, it did not work as expected because `local.domains[*].domain_name` did not produce a simple list of strings, but rather a more complex structure that is not directly compatible with `toset()`. The `for` expression resolves this issue by correctly flattening the structure into a simple list of strings.

---

> For me, this looks a little weird: `for_each = { for d in local.domains : d.domain_name => d.domain_name }`. You are simulating a list by creating a map that maps a domain to itself? :)

Yes, your understanding is correct! The expression `for_each = { for d in local.domains : d.domain_name => d.domain_name }` does indeed create a map where each key is mapped to the same value. That might seem a bit odd at first glance, but it is a useful technique in Terraform for a couple of reasons:

- **Uniqueness of keys**: In Terraform, when using `for_each`, the keys of the map need to be unique. By using the domain name as both the key and the value, you make sure each entry in the map is unique, which is a requirement for `for_each` to work correctly. That is particularly useful when the value (the domain name in this case) is already unique and encapsulates all the information needed for the iteration.
- **Ease of reference**: By setting the value to be the same as the key, you can easily reference the domain name in your resource configurations. Within the resource block, `each.key` and `each.value` will both give you the domain name, making your code more intuitive and easier to understand.
- **Flexibility for expansion**: That pattern also leaves room for easily expanding the configuration in the future. If you later need to include more information for each domain, you can adjust the map to include additional values while keeping the domain name as the key.

While it might seem redundant to map a value to itself, this approach is often used in Terraform to satisfy the unique key constraint of `for_each` and to make the code more flexible and maintainable.

---

> If `local.domains` is a list of strings, then `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)` would not work?
> In that case, what is `domain_name` referring too? :)

If `local.domains` is a list of strings, the expression `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)` would indeed not work as expected: when `local.domains` is a simple list of strings, like `["www.example.com", "api.example.com"]`, each element of the list is just a string, not an object or map. So, it does not have any attributes or named fields like `domain_name` to access.

The `[*].domain_name` part is a use of the [splat operator](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat), which is intended for use with lists of complex types (like objects or maps) to access a named attribute on each element. When applied to a list of simple strings, it does not make sense because there is no `domain_name` attribute on a string.

In the scenario where `local.domains` is a list of strings, converting it to a set would be straightforward with just `toset(local.domains)`:

```
for_each = toset(local.domains)
```

In this case, `local.domains` itself is directly a list of domain names (strings), and `toset()` converts this list into a set for use with `for_each`. There is no need to use the splat operator since you are not accessing an attribute of a complex type, but rather directly using the string values in the list.

---

> Do you know what is the difference between `domain_name` and `target_domain_name` for `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name`?

Yes, in the context of the [`aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_domain_name) in Terraform, `domain_name` and `target_domain_name` refer to two different aspects of the API Gateway custom domain setup

- **[`domain_name`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_domain_name#domain_name)**: That is the custom domain name that you are setting up for your API Gateway. It is the domain that clients will use to access your API. For example, if you have a custom domain like `api.mycompany.com`, this is what you would specify as the `domain_name`. That is essentially the public-facing URL that you want to map to your API Gateway.
- **[`target_domain_name`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_domain_name#target_domain_name)**: That attribute is part of the `domain_name_configuration` block within the `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resource. It refers to the hostname that API Gateway assigns to your deployed API. That is the actual endpoint that API Gateway creates and maintains, and it is different from the custom domain name you provide. The `target_domain_name` is used internally by AWS to route requests to your API Gateway.

When setting up a custom domain in API Gateway, you typically point your custom domain (`domain_name`) to the AWS-generated target domain (`target_domain_name`) using a DNS record (like a CNAME or an Alias record in Route 53). That setup makes sure when users hit your custom domain, the request is routed correctly to your API Gateway's target domain, and from there, to your API's deployment stage.

In short: `domain_name` is the custom domain you want to use for your API, while `target_domain_name` is the AWS-generated endpoint to which your custom domain should point.

---

> It still says `each.value.domain_name_configuration is list of object with 1 element` after applying your solution.

The error message indicating that `each.value.domain_name_configuration is a list of objects with 1 element` suggests that there is a mismatch between how the Terraform resource `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` is structured and how you are trying to access its attributes in the `aws_route53_record` and other related resources.

When you define a resource with `for_each`, each instance of that resource is a map where the key is defined by the `for_each` expression and the value is the resource itself. If `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway` is defined with `for_each`, `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.key]` or `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway[each.value]` will refer to individual instances of the `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resource.

If your `aws_route53_record` resource configuration is:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "api_gateway" {
  for_each = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_gateway

  name    = each.value.domain_name_configuration.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = local.domain_to_hosted_zone[each.key]

  alias {
    name                   = each.value.domain_name_configuration.target_domain_name
    zone_id                = each.value.domain_name_configuration.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Then make sure you are accessing the attributes of the `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resource correctly. The resource might have a different structure than anticipated.

Review the Terraform documentation for `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` to confirm the structure of the resource and how its attributes should be accessed. The `domain_name_configuration` might be a list, and if so, you would need to access its first element, like `each.value.domain_name_configuration[0].target_domain_name`.

Use `terraform state show` to inspect the state of an individual `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name` resource. That can give you a clear view of its structure and help you understand how to access its attributes.

Make sure your Terraform code is compatible with the version of the AWS provider you are using. Sometimes, attributes or their structures can change between versions.

And double-check the syntax and make sure there are no typos or incorrect references in your Terraform configuration.

---

> Isn't there a way to debug Terraform to make it display the values of locals or variables at deployment time? It would make it so much simpler to troubleshoot errors.
> I know of terraform console, but it's both cumbersome, and it's difficult to replicate real code.

As you mentioned, `terraform console` is a useful tool for experimenting with Terraform expressions. But if you want alternative, you might consider:

- **Output variables** to print values during `terraform apply` or `terraform plan`. This is a simple yet effective way to see the values of variables, locals, or any expression. Define an output in your configuration like this:

  ```
  output "local_domains" {
     value = local.domains
  }
  ```

  After running `terraform apply` or `terraform plan`, Terraform will display the values of these outputs.
- **Debug logging** that can be enabled by setting the `TF_LOG` environment variable. This can provide a lot of insight into what Terraform is doing, but the logs can be quite verbose. Use it like this:

  ```bash
  TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply
  ```

  Keep in mind that debug logs can contain sensitive information, so be cautious about where and how you share these logs.
- **Refactoring for clarity**, breaking down complex expressions into simpler, more atomic parts can help in understanding and debugging. This might involve using more locals to hold intermediate values so you can output and inspect them easily.

Comment: Thank you! Why doesn't `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)` work? I expect this expression to return a set of domain names. `local.domain[*].domain_name` iterates over each domain and extract the domain name? Yes, `local.domains` is defined as a list of objects

Comment: Isn't there a way to debug Terraform to make it display the values of locals or variables at deployment time? It would make it so much simpler to troubleshoot errors. I know of `terraform console`, but it's both cumbersome, and it's difficult to replicate real code

Comment: For me, this looks a little weird: `for_each = { for d in local.domains : d.domain_name => d.domain_name }`. You're simulating a list by creating a map that maps a domain to itself? :)

Comment: If `local.domains` is a list of strings, then `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)` wouldn't work? In that case, what is `domain_name` referring too? :)

Comment: Do you know what's the difference between `domain_name` and `target_domain_name` for `aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name`?

Comment: It still says `each.value.domain_name_configuration is list of object with 1 element` after applying your solution

Comment: @Shuzheng Hi there, thank you for those feedback. I have edited the answer to address your comments, one by one.

Comment: Thank you! I your solution now works. You need to index as follows `each.value.domain_name_configuration[0].target_domain_name`. I don't know why, but Terraform docs show up example. Furthermore, I could use `toset(local.domains[*].domain_name)` instead of `for_each = { for d in local.domains : d.domain_name => d.domain_name }`

Comment: Regarding `output`s - yes, they're useful. But the problem is that their values are only shown after the `apply` has succeeded? When there is an error, it can't complete, and consequently, I can't see the error?

Comment: @Shuzheng True. As an alternative, `terraform plan` can give some hints. And `terraform refresh` should help update the state file with the latest state of your resources as known to Terraform, which might allow outputs to be shown if they do not depend on the resources causing the apply failure.

Comment: Thanks for these hints regarding `terraform plan` and `terraform refresh` for displaying outputs. In general, I would like some more elaborate tools for debugging it

Comment: @Shuzheng I agree, those tools are not a good fit for debugging.